# What is the difference between Runtime.exec() and running shell commands in a terminal on android

Tags: java, android, shell, terminal, sh

My Motorola G6 is rooted and I have an application that should write to a root file to switch between host mode and device mode. The file is as follows:

> /sys/class/power_supply/usb/usb_otg

In android terminal emulator I type the following commands:

```
$    su
#    echo 3 > /sys/class/power_supply/usb/usb_otg
```

and these commands will put the phone into host mode. I know this because the phone is connected to a spectrometer and it is powered when I execute this command.

Since testing these commands I have put the following code into my application:

```
toastMessage("Attempting to power up spectrometer");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("echo 3 > /sys/class/power_supply/usb/usb_otg");
toastMessage("Reached this point");
```

This code doesn't appear to have any errors, it runs to the end but it doesn't power the spectrometer.

My question is why do these commands work in Android Terminal Emulator but not through Runtime.exec()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use this code

```
    toastMessage("Attempting to power up spectrometer");
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c \"\"echo 3 > /sys/class/power_supply/usb/usb_otg");
    toastMessage("Reached this point");
```

You need to execute su and other code in one code.
The second time you want execute the Runtime code it will execute without su privileges.

Comment: Thanks I'll try this soon, but since I posted this question I read somewhere that Runtime.exec() handles white space in a rather unintuitive way, which would explain why my code didn't work, do you know if this is the case, and if so would your code still work if so?

Comment: My code works well (I use it in my app), you need to use it in this way: su "echo something", but this " is special character so you need to use it with \"

Comment: That's great it seems to work well for my code now too. Thanks Pavel.